# What is YUVrecon video produced by HEVC encoder?

Tags: hevc, h.265, libx265, video-compression

What is YUVrecon video file produced by HEVC encoder along with .HEVC file at the end?

Someone told me:
HEVC file is produced by HEVC encoder.
HEVC decoder is also working and YUV recon is decoded result of .HEVC file.

And another friend told me:
YUV recon is just for debugging purposes. It is not decoded result of .HEVC file produced by encoder. So, we cannot use this YUVrecon video file to check the compression ratios, bitrate and other results.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The YUV file is the result of HEVC encoder, you want to check the performance like bitrate, compression ratio. You need orignal YUV file(The input of HEVC encoder). so, just use bitstream file cannot check performance of HEVC encoder.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your "another friend"! It is mostly used for debugging and is not necessarily what you would have if you decoded your bitstream.

For example, if you make a change to the encoder that breaks something internally, then you would have a mismatch between the encoder-side and the decoder-side reconstructed YUV file. Personally, I use this comparison to find the starting point (pixel or CU) of a bug.

Regarding your other question, I don't understand how one can use a YUV file for rate comparison. Basically, YUV files are uncompressed and do not carry any information about the compression rate. What you need for compression ratio analysis, is the compressed bitstream, not the reconstructed YUV file.